# How to simplify the codes of a list in one line in R?

Tags: r, list, function, sapply

I have a list of microarray platform text files containing of Gene Symbol accessions. I trim Gene Symbols with below codes.

```
p[[1]]<- data.frame(sapply(p[[1]], function(x) sub("/.*", "", x)))
p[[1]]<- data.frame(sapply(p[[1]], function(x) sub("-.*", "", x)))
p[[1]]<- data.frame(sapply(p[[1]], function(x) sub("\\..*", "", x)))
p[[1]]<- data.frame(sapply(p[[1]], function(x) sub("\\s", "", x)))
p[[2]]<- data.frame(sapply(p[[2]], function(x) sub("/.*", "", x)))
p[[2]]<- data.frame(sapply(p[[2]], function(x) sub("-.*", "", x)))
p[[2]]<- data.frame(sapply(p[[2]], function(x) sub("\\..*", "", x)))
p[[2]]<- data.frame(sapply(p[[2]], function(x) sub("\\s", "", x)))
```

How can I simplify these codes in two lines?
Thank so much for any idea.

Comment: you'll get better answers if you make your question [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example](reproducible). You could also define a function to store your steps that way you don't have to maintain so many duplicative lines of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use regex's pipe operator that equates to the logical `OR`:

```
p[[1]] <- data.frame(sapply(p[[1]], function(x) sub("/.*|-.*|\\..*|\\s", "", x)))

p[[2]] <- data.frame(sapply(p[[2]], function(x) sub("/.*|-.*|\\..*|\\s", "", x)))
```